# Extreme slow starting of JBoss AS 7.1.0 in debug mode

Tags: eclipse, debugging, jboss7.x

I am using Eclipse Juno with JBoss Tools, m2e plugin, etc. to work with JBoss AS.
When I start the server normally (non-debug), everything is deploying very fast, but when I start JBoss AS 7.1.0 in debug mode (via the 'Servers' tab) the deployment is very very slow.

It is an JSF 2.0 .war (with RichFaces addon).

If I start JBoss in debug mode manually (via JAVA_OPTS) everything works fine.

Does anybody of you know any troubleshooting?

Here is the console output: http://pastebin.com/7GfDCTMw
See the delay between line 53 and 54

Comment: Could this be a memory issue? how much max mem did you have set? (Xmx)

Answer (score 6):

Remove all the break points  in your code  and start jboss in debugging mode,
 than after jboss start in debugging mode add debugging points in to your code.

Comment: This worked for me.  Just to elaborate, this seems to show up when my number of breakpoints gets high.  Also keep in mind that if you don't want to lose your breakpoints, disabling them in the breakpoints window inside Eclipse seems to work just as well.